Proving convergence of rational function from first principles
The full question and solutions are,
here
However, the bit I am confused on is how they get $$| x - 4 | > \frac{1}{2}$$ from. I have tried deriving that expression from two different methods. Here is the first method:
$$-1\frac{1}{2} < x - 4 < -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$1\frac{1}{2} > -(x - 4) > \frac{1}{2}$$
$$|1\frac{1}{2}| > |-(x - 4)| > |\frac{1}{2}|$$
$$1\frac{1}{2} > |-1||x - 4| > \frac{1}{2}$$
$$1\frac{1}{2} > |x - 4| > \frac{1}{2}$$
However, I also have an alternative method, but I am unsure why it is not giving the correct expression. Here the second method:
$$-1\frac{1}{2} < x - 4 < -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$|-1\frac{1}{2}| < |x - 4| < |-\frac{1}{2}|$$
$$1\frac{1}{2} < |x - 4| < \frac{1}{2}$$
Does someone please know what I have done wrong?
Thanks!

For your alternative method, all of $-1\frac12$, $x-4$ and $-\frac12$ are negative. You may check with example that for negative $a,b$, if $a<b$ then $\lvert a\rvert > \lvert b\rvert$.

Thank you @peterwhy!
